# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS booting time longer than usual

Tags: boot

My device is taking longer than usual to start up and the logo is not appearing.

The `systemd-analyze blame` output http://pastebin.com/M8gV7Hn8

Comment: Did you recently install any other Linux OS alongside with Ubuntu?

Comment: You could try `bootchart` as additional analyzing tool if it comes to boot process

Comment: @Raphael No. Ubuntu is the only operating system.

Answer (score 1):

### Optimize Startup

You can optimize your system startup process by looking at the lines that are executed on startup.  Pick out applications that you might not need or don't want to use.

Also, if the system is hanging up on a process use this described feature to identify which process is taking a long time, then address or fix the offending process.

**An example of system hanging**

I had lived with a long startup process for a while.  I turned off the splash and noticed that during some maintenance my swap partition UUID had changed (an `/etc/fstab` entry).  In this case I edited out the swap assignment to that process.  When it cured the delay, I replaced the UUID with a current active partition to cure the delay and have swap.

**Locate the problem line**

To see the lines that are executing, edit your Grub `/etc/default/grub` and remove the `quiet splash` from the `GRUB-CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` configuration.  The line to change is highlighted in bold text.

Change from:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update               
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.                                                          
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:                      
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'                                      
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"                                                        
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="15"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Change to:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update               
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.                                                          
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:                      
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'                                      

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"                                                        
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="15"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then execute:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot.

*You might find you're running a service or services you can do without.  Or you may find you'd prefer to contend with the time it takes in loading a service over removing it.*

After you have identified and fixed the problem causing the delay you can return the default screen by adding the `quit` and `splash` modes to your grub.

Comment: how to remove the service which I don't want?

Comment: @aadhi00 By running `systemctl disable what_you_found.service`